# Flash + IE9 + 'Do not save encrypted pages to disk' checked

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, http, https, browser-cache

I have an adobe flex application that does an xml ajax request to populate a graph.  I have an issue where a customer won't uncheck the 'Do not save encrypted pages to disk' setting in IE and when they load the graphs, they get a 'Server communication error'.

I have tried several combinations of headers:

```
// works in IE8, but not IE9
Pragma => ''
Cache-control => '' 

// works in IE8, but not IE9
Pragma => ''
Cache-control => 'no-store' 

// works in IE8, but not IE9
Pragma => 'public'
Cache-control => 'max-age=0' 

// doesn't work in IE8 or IE9
Pragma => 'no-cache'
Cache-control => 'no-cache,max-age=30,must-revalidate'
```

Can someone tell me the magic voodoo that will make it work in all versions of IE > 8

Or, is there some weird setting on my windows test vm that is causing the cache headers to be ignored.

It seems like the general approved solution I find by doing lots of google searches is to just uncheck the IE setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `POST` request instead of `GET` to avoid any caching.
As far as I know, none of the browser caches the `POST` requests

HIH
M.

Comment: I just verified, a POST request does not fix the issue.

Comment: I am quiet surprised... anyway, another trick is to add a parameter to the url that changes everytime. For instance, suffix all your requests by a parameter `?requestedAt=<now>`.

Comment: What you are referring to is when you want to make sure the browser always shows a fresh page.  But, the browser also has rules that tell what to do with content when it gets it.  If you have the "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" setting unchecked, the browser could still write your response to disk even though it has a random string in the url.  The browser will still show a fresh page, but it would be written to disk.  In the context of flash, flex can't access the content and an error occurs when this setting is checked.

Comment: Here, the guy says http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/07/downloads-and-flash-fail-when-do-not-save-encrypted-pages-to-disk-is-set.aspx : This option is universal for HTTPS responses; their headers (e.g. Pragma, Cache-Control) ***are not consulted*** Are you mixing a swf loaded from HTTP and data coming from HTTPS? I already had issues because of "unsure context" in IE

Comment: The swf is loading, but when the swf lods, the xml request (over https) fails.